# Dynamic update to custom property

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am using polymer v1.9.1 and testing on Chrome.

I have a custom element containing a `<paper-input>`, and I want its text color to depend on some other property. This color is [determined](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/1.x/paper-input-container.html#L86) by the custom properties `--paper-input-container-input-color` or `--primary-text-color`, so I set a class-dependent value for those:

```
#input { --primary-text-color: red; }
#input.green { --primary-text-color: green; }
```

```
<paper-input id='input' class$='[[_getClasses(checked)]]'></paper-input>
```

```
_getClasses: function(checked) { return checked ? '':'green'; }
```

The text is always red, I guess because of [this limitation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#custom-properties-shim-limitations) in the shim (which I guess my browser must be using). So I add a call to `updateStyles`:

```
_getClasses: function(checked) {
  this.async(function() {
    this.$.input.updateStyles();
  });
  return checked ? '':'green'; }
}
```

Now it works correctly after `checked` first changes, **but** the initial state is incorrect (ie if `checked` is initially false, it is initially red but should be green). I tried adding another `async(updateStyles())` to `ready` but no luck (yet if I call input.updateStyles() from the javascript console it corrects itself). How can I work around this?

Complete example: http://embed.plnkr.co/VC1ZMw9iyUO3K2SQq5Oy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/MY5aJM5PFPBkp6bgUbfX?p=preview) with the fix.
I've updated styles in `attached` callback instead of `ready`.

```
_getClasses: function(checked) {
    return checked ? '' : 'green';
  },
  attached: function() {
    this.updateStyles();
  }
```

Comment: btw it doesn't work for me unless I keep updateStyles in _getClasses too (I guess it's browser dependent :/). But with calls from both _getClasses and attached it works as expected, thanks!

Comment: Oh right ! That's probably because when you change by checking/unchecking the checkbox we need to trigger `updateStyles` again.

Comment: Help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566067/data-binding-between-parent-child-in-polymer1-0/44568308#44568308